# Broadcast from legacy code to Angular via rootScope

Tags: javascript, factory, broadcast, legacy, angularjs

I am trying to broadcast a message from legacy javascript function into Angular controller(s) via a Angular service. Broadcasting works fine when called within Angular, but not outside.
See http://jsfiddle.net/yh3Ds/24/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that `angular.injector()` is creating new module instance and
it is independent from the module instance bound with the html via `ng-app` attribute.

So solution is to use manual bootstrap and obtain the injector there.
Use this injector you can access the service instance and `$rootScope` which 
is actually controlling the view.

Here is the updated fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/d8vX3/1/